Getting issues while updating googleapis from version 100.0.0 to 144.0.0
I am updating my googleapis package in my mern project
so here I am using googleapis to create and export data in google sheets
while updating I am facing some issues related to type of the authentication as JWT  or oAuth
here is my code
export const authenticate = async () => {

  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: path.join(__dirname + "/../config/google-apis-config.json"),
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
  });
  
  const client = await auth.getClient();

  return client;
};

export const getDataFromSheet = async (sheetId: string, sheetName: string) => {

  let client = await authenticate();
  let Sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: client });
  
  const request = {
    spreadsheetId: sheetId,
    range: sheetName,
    auth: client,
    majorDimension: 'ROWS'
  };
  const response = await Sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request);

  const data = response?.data?.values;

  return { cols: data?.shift(), rows: data };
}

here is the error i am getting
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(version: "v4"): Sheets', gave the following error.
Argument of type '{ version: string; auth: JWT | UserRefreshClient | BaseExternalAccountClient | ExternalAccountAuthorizedUserClient | ... 6 more ... | PassThroughClient; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '"v4"'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(options: Options): Sheets', gave the following error.
Type 'JWT | UserRefreshClient | BaseExternalAccountClient | ExternalAccountAuthorizedUserClient | ... 6 more ... | PassThroughClient' is not assignable to type 'string | BaseExternalAccountClient | GoogleAuth | OAuth2Client'.
Type 'ExternalAccountAuthorizedUserClient' is not assignable to type 'string | BaseExternalAccountClient | GoogleAuth | OAuth2Client'.
Type 'ExternalAccountAuthorizedUserClient' is missing the following properties from type 'OAuth2Client': certificateCache, certificateExpiry, certificateCacheFormat, refreshTokenPromises, and 27 more.ts(2769)
api.d.ts(24, 5): The expected type comes from property 'auth' which is declared here on type 'Options'
(property) GeneratedAPIs.sheets: (version: "v4") => sheets_v4.Sheets (+1 overload)
I have tries different ways to authenticate from google documentation
but everywhere I am getting the same code for the login authentication

When I tested your showing script with googleapis@144.0.0 using my service account, no error occurred. The values could be correctly retrieved from Spreadsheet with Sheets API. Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation. I apologize for this. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By the way, /../config/google-apis-config.json is for the service account. Is my understanding correct?

thanks Tanaike for trying on your end
but somehow it's working now on my end. I have just removed const client = await auth.getClient();  and has use auth directly while making a sheet

Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.
